# Bash - How to continue executing script after 'exec' or 'source' finishes running another script?

Tags: bash

I am writing a post update script for proxmox since some edits to the webserver are overwritten every time it gets updated. It removes a popup you get after login and applies a dark theme. The theme is written by someone else and I want to pull their code to stay up to date.

Here is the script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f PVEDiscordDark.sh ]; then
  rm PVEDiscordDark.sh
fi

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Weilbyte/PVEDiscordDark/master/PVEDiscordDark.sh
exec PVEDiscordDark.sh install

echo "Removing \"No Subscription\" pop-up"
sed -i.backup -z "s/res === null || res === undefined || \!res || res\n\t\t\t.data.status.toLowerCase() \!== 'active'/false/g" /usr/share/javascript/proxmox-widget-toolkit/proxmoxlib.js

echo "Restarting pveproxy.service. This may take a minute."
systemctl restart pveproxy.service
```

Right now, it will install the theme and stop there, I guess this is due to the script I am calling. I even tested this like:

foo.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "foo"
```

foobar.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source foo.sh
echo "bar"
```

outputs:

```
foo
bar
```

What I need this script to do is run the PVEDiscordDark.sh and output to the terminal, then after it is finished run the sed command, and finally restart the webserver. Restarting the webserver MUST come last as it could take over a minute to come back.

What can I do to stop PVEDiscordDark from ending the script after it is finished?

Comment: Your code will keep running after a `source`, but `exec` never returns because your process has been replaced.  You don't need to use `exec` just to run another script.

Comment: I have tried both exec and source, both stop after running PVEDiscordDark.sh

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace this line:

```
exec PVEDiscordDark.sh install
```

with this

```
./PVEDiscordDark.sh install
```

You do not need `exec`, just run the script

Comment: I didn't actually know it was appropriate to do that within a script. That didn't actually work without running chmod 755 though. The PVEDiscordDark github says to run it with ```bash PVEDiscordDark.sh install```, which did work, but I assumed it was not appropriate to do that either.

Comment: @ZenRen, correct. You should change the permissions. Or run via `bash` command. It's up to you to check the script before run it.